# Weblogic Cluster Installation

Tags: weblogic

I have to install a Weblogic server for Contribution. I have 2 machines with 2 diff host names.

In machine one (M1) I have installed a admin server(admin) with listen address to that machine host and a managed server (managed1). It has 2 machines, one for admin and another for managed1.

In another machine I need to install oly managed server (managed2), which should be controlled by admin of the M1.

I have not idea how to do it. It will be helpful if answer is step by step.

Comment: Have you even looked at the documentation? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13196_01/platform/docs81/confgwiz/multi.html You will need a nodemanagers running on your hosts as well to start the managed servers from the admin console.

Answer (score 0):

On one M1 you have installed admin and manged1 perfect. 
next on M1 only through console create another managed2, but in configuration tab settings of managed2 give listen address of M2(machine 2)
To get the listen address do "ifconfig" you will get ipaddress give the ipaddress in manged2 settings.